# update component on Vuex state change through computed properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am building a simple movie app using Vue and Vuex and want to be able to add movies to a favourites list when a button is clicked. I am adding the movies to the store but I want the text on the button to change from 'Add to favourites' to 'Remove from favourites' when the movie has been added. I am using a computed property to read the Vuex store to determine the text on the button based on whether the movie is in the favourites list in the store or not. If I reload the page, the text on the button changes correctly but I am unable to get the text to change when just clicking on the button to add/remove movie. How can I get the computed properties to be re computed on a change in the Vuex store?

Here is my movie component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="single-movie-page">
    <img class="movie-img" :src="movie.img"></img>
    <div class="single-movie-info">
      <h1>{{movie.title}}</h1>
      <h3>Rating: {{movie.stars}}</h3>
      <h3>Released Date: {{movie.releaseDate}}</h3>
      <p>{{movie.overview}}</p>
      <button v-on:click="addRemoveFavourites" >{{ favourite }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['movie'],
  computed: {
    favourite() {
      return this.$store.state.favourites[this.movie.id] === undefined
        ? 'Add to Favourites'
        : 'Remove from Favourites'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRemoveFavourites() {
      this.$store.commit('changeFavourites', this.movie)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is my Vuex store:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    favourites: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    changeFavourites: (state, movie) => {
      if (state.favourites[movie.id]) {
        delete state.favourites[movie.id]
      } else state.favourites[movie.id] = movie
    }
  }
})
```

I tried using `this.$forceUpdate()` in the addRemoveFavourites method, but this didn't work either.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I also forgot to take into account the fact that changing what is inside an object doesn't change the object itself. I tried using Object.assign but this didn't work. I guess I have to use these built in Vue methods.

Answer (score 5):

Bert has the right answer, you can't normally add/remove properties from an object and have them be reactive in Vuejs.

You need to use `Vue.set` and `Vue.delete` if you want them to be reactive.

So your mutation should look like this:

```
mutations: {
  changeFavourites: (state, movie) => {
    if (state.favourites[movie.id]) {
      Vue.delete(state.favourites, movie.id)
    } else {
      Vue.set(state.favourites, movie.id, movie)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, no problem!